# How can I get jQuery Zoom working with Slick Slider?

Tags: jquery, zooming, slick.js

I'm using jQuery Zoom to add zoom to my Slick Slider:
https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom

This is working fine in most situations, but unfortunately there is always one slide (cloned slide), that doesn't zoom. I've created a Codepen to reproduce the problem:

https://codepen.io/joostplas/pen/yKVeOx?q=slickslider&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

```html
 <div><img class="image-zoom" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2550/5316/products/sweaterwhitebycossac_front1_1440x.jpg?v=1520864793"/></div>
            <div><img class="image-zoom" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2550/5316/products/sweaterwhitebycossac_side_1440x.jpg?v=1520864793"/></div>
            <div><img class="image-zoom" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2550/5316/products/sweaterwhitebycossac_back_1440x.jpg?v=1520864793"/></div>
```

I think it is some conflict between Slick and Zoom, but I have no idea how to debug this. Any tips for me?

Answer (score 1):

Slick slider clones some HTML Nodes for infinite sliding, so the events which Zoom Plugin uses are not attached to the newly cloned Nodes made by Slick

You have to kill the Zoom plugin and re-initialise it again after a change of slick slide.

Try this js :

```
$('.images').on('click', function() {
  $('.lazy').slick({
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  initZoom()
});

function initZoom() {
    $('.image-zoom')
      .zoom({
      url: $(this).find('img').attr('data-zoom')
    });  
}

$('.lazy').on('afterChange', function() {
  $('.image-zoom').trigger('zoom.destroy');
  initZoom()
});
```

[Here is your codepen updated](https://codepen.io/sandwell/pen/qoqZxV)

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort!

Unfortunately I'm not managing to get your solution working on my live site:
http://www.thegreenlabels.com/products/crop-jumper-rust-by-cossac

I tried the following code, but no effect:

` $('.slickSlider ul').on('afterChange', function() {
  $('.image-zoom').trigger('zoom.destroy');
  initZoom()
});`

Comment: You have to listen to "afterChange" event on the same HTML node that you initialised the slider in the first place. I do not think you initialised your slider on ".slickSlider ul". I think you did it on "#ProductSlider"

Comment: Also tried this:
  `var SlickSlider = $t.slick({
        autoplay: $auto,
        autoplaySpeed: $time,
      });

      SlickSlider.on('afterChange', function(){
        console.log("This mos def fires");
        $('.image-zoom').trigger('zoom.destroy');
 initZoom()
    });`

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same result when I use `#ProductSlider`

Comment: I don't know what I can do more. My codepen works. I thnik I deserve a validation for that. Could you provide a snipet to reproduce the bug so I can look into it ?

Comment: You deserve all the credits in the world! It's much appreciated. I will try to improve my Codepen to mimic my code better. Thanks again!